# Ruby on Rails Error - NoMethodError in Admin::Store#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on Rails Error - NoMethodError in Admin::Store#new 
Here is my code and project structure. what is wrong with my code?
I generated this command "Rails generate controller admin/store"

generated controller

Controllers

```
/home/rok/Development/Pan/app/controllers/admin/store_controller.rb

    class Admin::StoreController < ApplicationController
             def new
               @store = Store.new
               #render "admin/store/new"
             end
     end
```

Views

```
    /home/rok/Development/Pan/app/views/admin/store/new.thml.erb

     <h1>xx </h1>
     <p> xx </p>

     <%= simple_form_for (@store) do |form| %>

     <div class="form-inputs">
             <%= form.input :store_name, label: "xx" %>
             <%= form.input :store_address, label: "xx" %>
             <%= form.input :store_phone, label: "xx" %>
             <%= form.input :store_logitude, label: "xx" %>
             <%= form.input :store_latitude, label: "xx" %>
     </div>

     <div class="form-actions">
             <%= form.button :submit %>
     </div>
     <% end %>
```

Models

```
    /home/rok/Development/Pan/app/models/store.rb

    class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :store_name, presence: true
      validates :store_address, presence: true
      validates :store_phone, presence: true
      validates :store_longitude, presence: true
      validates :store_latitude, presence: true
    end
```

NoMethodError in Admin::Store#new
Showing /home/rok/Development/Pan/app/views/admin/store/new.html.erb 
where line #4 raised:

undefined method `stores_path' for #<#:0x007f627c4ade00>
Extracted source (around line #4):
2
3
4
5
6
7

```
   <p> xx </p>

   <%= simple_form_for (@store) do |form| %>

   <div class="form-inputs">
       <%= form.input :store_name, label: "xx" %>
```

Rails.root: /home/rok/Development/Pan

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better to change your name controller into pluralize

```
rails generate controller admin/stores
```

**routes.rb**

You have to do this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :stores
end
```

Then, in your form write it:

```
<%= simple_form_for ([:admin, @store]) do |form| %>
<% end %>
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give namespace as well:-

```
<%= simple_form_for ([:admin,@store]) do |form| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i show this error
 undefined method `admin_stores_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f627cd7cab8>:0x007f627c13f930>

Comment: please post your `config/routes.rb`

Comment: @Rajarshi Das 
get 'admin/store/list' => 'admin/store#list'
get 'admin/store/new' => 'admin/store#new'

Comment: ahh thats why `namespace :admin do resources :stores end` try this

Comment: @RajarshiDas I was No route matches [GET] "/admin/store/new"

Comment: @YoungrokLim could you please post your routes?

Comment: @user3506853 
I was 
       #get 'admin/store/list' => 'admin/store#list'
       #get 'admin/store/new' => 'admin/store#new'
current
      namespace :admin do resources :stores end